# Can a gluon split into three gluons: $g \rightarrow ggg$? (four gluon vertex)

Tags: standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, interactions, gluons

I know $gg \rightarrow gg$ is possible, but is $g \rightarrow ggg$ possible? I don't see this anywhere although I think you could conserve colour charge (e.g.  $r\bar{g} \rightarrow r\bar{g} + g\bar{b} + \bar{g}b$) and even total angular momentum, or is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: The color specific process you wrote as an example is really the answer to your question since you can write that as $g\to g g \bar{g}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking whether there can be a colorless 4-gluon vertex, group theoretically, the answer is "of course", since $8\otimes 8\otimes 8\otimes 8$ contains a singlet.

It is the celebrated term in the QCD lagrangian,
$$
g^2 f^{abc}f^{aeh}A^b_{[\mu} A^c_{\nu]}A^{e~~[\mu}A^{h~~\nu]}.
$$

Gluons are always virtual, so, indeed, the four-gluon vertex features in many QCD perturbative calculations.